# How to add distinct keyword on keys in sql while joining 2 tables

Tags: sql

```sql
select * from 
  employee 
    left join 
  orders 
    on employee.emp_id = orders.emp.id
```

here i want to select only distinct elements from **orders.emp.id**

Comment: you try to select * from both tables of the join. You have to know which fields you want to make distinct

Comment: can you please add a few sample records with the result you want to achieve ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure reasonet's answer below does what you want, but some examples would make your requirements much more clear.

Comment: why you are using that `left join`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do "select distinct orders.emp.id from your_joined_tables".